# Trying to send byte array to server yields error: Trying to send command for object without authority

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

I have no idea why this is happening. I'm creating an object and then trying to send it as a byte array from my client to my server across a local network and I'm getting the error `Trying to send command for object without authority.` when multiple clients are connected to the server simultaneously. If I'm creating an object that's a serialized byte array, how do give it authority?

The full error I'm getting is

```
Trying to send command for object without authority.
UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkBehaviour:SendCommandInternal(NetworkWriter, Int32, String)
Network_Transmitter:CallCmdPrepareToReceiveBytes(Int32, Int32)
<DoSendBytes>c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at Assets/Scripts/Networking/Network_Transmitter.cs:46)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
Player_Data:PrepareServerData() (at Assets/Scripts/Player/Player_Data.cs:77)
Event_Manager:SendTextureData() (at Assets/Scripts/Event_Manager.cs:31)
Game_UI:SendData() (at Assets/Scripts/Game_UI.cs:39)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()
```

The object I'm creating:

```
[Serializable]
public class PlayerObject
{
    public byte[] texBytes;
    public int texWidth;
    public int texHeight;
    public TextureFormat texFormat;
    public float tranX;
    public float tranY;
    public float tranZ;
    public string type;
    public string id;
    public int strength;
    public int hitpoints;
}
```

and the functions where the error is occurring is here:

```
[Client]
    public IEnumerator DoSendBytes(int transmissionId, byte[] data)
    {
        Debug.Assert(!clientTransmissionIds.Contains(transmissionId));
        Debug.Log(LOG_PREFIX + "SendBytesToClients processId=" + transmissionId + " | datasize=" + data.Length);

        //tell server that he is going to receive some data and tell him how much it will be.
        CmdPrepareToReceiveBytes(transmissionId, data.Length);
        yield return null;

        //begin transmission of data. send chunks of 'bufferSize' until completely transmitted.
        clientTransmissionIds.Add(transmissionId);
        TransmissionData dataToTransmit = new TransmissionData(data);
        int bufferSize = defaultBufferSize;
        while (dataToTransmit.curDataIndex < dataToTransmit.data.Length - 1)
        {
            //determine the remaining amount of bytes, still need to be sent.
            int remaining = dataToTransmit.data.Length - dataToTransmit.curDataIndex;
            if (remaining < bufferSize)
                bufferSize = remaining;

            //prepare the chunk of data which will be sent in this iteration
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            System.Array.Copy(dataToTransmit.data, dataToTransmit.curDataIndex, buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            //send the chunk
            CmdReceiveBytes(transmissionId, buffer);
            dataToTransmit.curDataIndex += bufferSize;

            yield return null;

            if (null != OnDataFragmentSent)
                OnDataFragmentSent.Invoke(transmissionId, buffer);
        }

        //transmission complete.
        clientTransmissionIds.Remove(transmissionId);

        if (null != OnDataComepletelySent)
            OnDataComepletelySent.Invoke(transmissionId, dataToTransmit.data);
    }

    [Command]
    private void CmdPrepareToReceiveBytes(int transmissionId, int expectedSize)
    {
        if (serverTransmissionData.ContainsKey(transmissionId))
            return;

        //prepare data array which will be filled chunk by chunk by the received data
        TransmissionData receivingData = new TransmissionData(new byte[expectedSize]);
        serverTransmissionData.Add(transmissionId, receivingData);
    }

    //use reliable sequenced channel to ensure bytes are sent in correct order
    [Command]
    private void CmdReceiveBytes(int transmissionId, byte[] recBuffer)
    {
        //already completely received or not prepared?
        if (!serverTransmissionData.ContainsKey(transmissionId))
            return;

        //copy received data into prepared array and remember current dataposition
        TransmissionData dataToReceive = serverTransmissionData[transmissionId];
        System.Array.Copy(recBuffer, 0, dataToReceive.data, dataToReceive.curDataIndex, recBuffer.Length);
        dataToReceive.curDataIndex += recBuffer.Length;

        if (null != OnDataFragmentReceived)
            OnDataFragmentReceived(transmissionId, recBuffer);

        if (dataToReceive.curDataIndex < dataToReceive.data.Length - 1)
            //current data not completely received
            return;

        //current data completely received
        Debug.Log(LOG_PREFIX + "Completely Received Data at transmissionId=" + transmissionId);
        serverTransmissionData.Remove(transmissionId);

        if (null != OnDataCompletelyReceived)
            OnDataCompletelyReceived.Invoke(transmissionId, dataToReceive.data);
    }
```

The entire project can be found here: https://github.com/kenmarold/HLAPI-Prototype

Comment: I haven't used Unity's builtin networking system that much, but it sounds as though the `NetworkIdentity` of the `gameObject` which has the script you're sending data through needs local authority.

Comment: That makes sense, but the object that I'm sending is just in memory, i'm creating the object in a class, it's not actually a gameobject.

Comment: Indeed, however you're sending it **through** Unity's networking system where it is executed on a `NetworkIdentity`.  You don't need to change what you're sending, you need to change whatever `NetworkIdentity` you're using to send it.

Comment: Right, this is where I'm confused, the script is getting executed on a GameObject that has a network identity set to client authority, which is also assigned as my player object in the Network Manager component.

Comment: When you say client authority, I assume you've got the `Local Player Authority` checked on the server and are using `NetworkServer.Spawn` to summon the object on the client?

Comment: On the client I have a player with the network identity set to local player authority. On that player i have the script above along with other scripts that create a PlayerObject populated with all the data that I want to send to the server that I then convert to a byte array and serialize to send. On the server side I have a script that instantiates a GameObject using `NetworkServer.SpawnWithClientAuthority(go, connectionToClient);` from there I assign the PlayerObject data I sent from the client to that newly spawned GameObject

Comment: Yeah, what I believe you want to do is have the script which is running commands on the `gameObject` spawned by the server, as this is the `gameObject` with local authority.

Comment: So you’re saying the server needs to spawn the player objects on each client? Is that how it should be done? I’ve never thought of it that way. I always thought that the player objects were always locally/spawned from each client.

Comment: I would take a look at the documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-NetworkIdentity.html